# Creating dynamic N to N connections using 0MQ

Tags: network-programming, zeromq

I wanted to create an application that will be able to run on multiple machines and store some information. I would then be able to query any given instance of it (knowing its address) and get back the data.

If again this particular instance does not have this data then it should be able to query the other instances and see if it can find it.

The hard thing with this is that new instances might be opened or closed at any time.

During my earlier tests what I did was have static connections and each time one of those came online it would report the data it held to the others. This is not practical though.

What would be a good way to achieve this?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure to understand 100%, correct me if I am wrong: you have several instances of an application, you want to request these instances using _another_ application. You know the list of your instances addresses, but you don't know when they are online or not.
Another thing: what do you mean by _If again this particular instance does not have this data then it should be able to query the other instances and see if it can find it._ Does the instance you request should request other instances?

Comment: @vtellier not exactly. what I meant was that I have a number of peers, each peer is responsible for storing and making available to the clients some data, lets say a song. When I log into a peer and I search for a song , if it is there then it's fine, but if not I want to be able to get it from the peer that has this song. I dont know if this is a useful design but it does not matter since I am simply doing it to learn 0mq. My problem is in somehow making and managing the connections to a variable number of peers.

Comment: Ok I see. Actually it is not the easiest because (once again if I understand well) you need at some point to know who own the song. This means maintaining a list of songs and so know all the peers in the topology (dynamic discovery). And this exercice is not easy at all : [The Dynamic Discovery Problem](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#toc38) in the guide, you cannot also read about read in the same guide or on the [github repo](https://github.com/zeromq/zyre).

To simplify this, I would add a special node acting like a proxy, it will make the discovery easier.

Comment: I did try the solution of adding a node adding as a proxy and it worked quite well. The N to N connection then popped in my mind but it's significantly harder to pull off I think. I will have a look at zyre though, thanks for the link.